# Missing operating system error after change of active partition in DOS OS

Tags: laptop, freedos

By mistake i changed the active partition in dos os and now my laptop is not booting and just giving the message "MISSING OPERATING SYSTEM". My laptop came with dos os only and am not able to install any other OS now as the size of the drive shown now is just 870MB. Please do help me out

Comment: You have to specify which partition is the boot partition. Just like in Linux. I do not know however how to do this but I would assume it would require configuring a boot loader.

Comment: Actualy am new to dos,linux.. I need some steps to change back this partition and then install windows.

Comment: If your trying to install Windows you need to change the partition to a NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to install an operating system, just boot from it. If you have a DOS boot diskette, you can boot from it and set the active partition with fdisk, as usual.

If you don't, you could, e.g., download the [Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (or [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)) LiveCD, [burn it to a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or create a [bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and do the following:

1. Boot from your Live CD and click **Try Ubuntu** when it asks whether to try or install it.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type *gparted* and click **GParted Partition Editor**.
3. Go to **GParted → Devices** and select the proper hard drive.
4. Right-click the partition that should be active, choose **Manage Flags**, select **boot** and click **Close**.
5. Click **Edit → Apply All Operations**.
6. Reboot.

Comment: Problem is there is just 870MB cos the other partition only has 900GB. Is it possible to install ubuntu within this space?

Comment: You do not need to install Ubuntu. It's a Live CD, i.e., Ubuntu runs from the CD/DVD/flash drive itself. Nothing gets actually written to the hard disk.

Comment: Oh k.. Thanks buddy.. Can you give me a torrent link to download that live ubuntu?  By using this live cd i can change the partition and then install windows??

Comment: The official Ubuntu torrents can be found in the [alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) on the Ubuntu website. Yes, you can resize and create partitions with GParted. It's a fully functional partition manager.

Comment: There are actually 2 versions - desktop,server.. Which 1 shud i download fr my laptop??

Comment: Desktop. The server version has no graphical user interface.

Comment: I have to download both ubuntu and Gparted??

Comment: No. The Ubuntu Live CD comes with GParted.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks Dennis.. Will try it out and comment..